# Check Arguments on Meteor.call(...)

Tags: meteor

### #Meteor v. 1.0# Meteor.call(title, description) throws an exception

**Check the Arguments on the client:**

```
'click div[name="saveCollection"]' : function(e) {
    var title = 'Title'
    var description = 'Description'

    check(title, String) 
    check(description, String)

    Match.test(title, String)        --> It's true    
    Match.test(description, String)  --> It's also true 

    Meteor.call('saveCollection', title, description, function(error, result){
    ...
    })
}
```

**Check the Arguments on the server:**

```
saveCollection: function (title, description) {
    check(title, String)
    check(description, String)

    Match.test(title, String)        --> It's true  
    Match.test(description, String)  --> It's also true  

    Collection.insert({
       title: title,
       description: description
   })
}
```

```
Exception while invoking method 'saveCollection' Error: Did not check() all arguments during call to 'saveCollection'
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: @Kyll, checking the arguments on the client (twice) is not normal nor necessary.

Comment: @j03I Is this the only instance in the codebase where `saveCollection` is called?

Comment: Maybe a workaround will work. On the server code, instead of calling `check()` with `title` and `description`, could you replace them respectively by `arguments[0]` and `arguments[1]`?

Comment: I have replaced the arguments, but The problem still exists. I will continue to keep trying :)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, don't you mean to be calling

```
Meteor.call('saveCollection', title, description)
```

rather than

```
Meteor.call('saveCollection', description, description)
```

This is probably messing up the audit-argument-checks.

Comment: Oh, then I miss understood Kylls comment. However, your suggestion should make no difference since both arguments are strings.

Comment: Some went wrong while i was typing my question. In my code I wrote: Meteor.call('saveCollection', title, description). The problem still exists.